# Typeahead 3 inside div overflow-x

Tags: jquery, html, css, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead

I have a div with class 'table-responsive' that has overflow-x setted to 'auto'.

Inside this div there is an input text with typeahead. When I found results to return into typeahead, is inside the div. How can I exit it?

Here my code:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Righe</legend>
        <table id="dettaglioDocumento" class="table table-condensed table-fixed" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <col width="50px">
        <col width="350px">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><label class="align-table">Descrizione</label></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="<?= $root; ?>/assets/img/details_close.png" class="link removeRow"></td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="txtDescrizione[]" data-target=".container-fluid" class="form-control selectDescrizione" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off" name="txtDescrizione_0" type="text" placeholder="" value="">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Here JS Code:

```
    $('.selectDescrizione').typeahead({
        minLength: 3,
        items: 5,
        delay: 400,
        source: function (query, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?= $root; ?>/get_listino',
                dataType: "json",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    query: query
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    return response(data.listino);
                }
            });
        },
        displayText: function (item) {
            return item.testo;
        }
    });
```

Here the pic:
[image]

***UPDATE***
[JSFiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/w11hwLLy/)

Comment: Have you tried `z-index`?

Comment: @abhishek-pandey yes, I tried to set it to an hight value but nothing...

Comment: If you could provide working fiddle of your code, that would be much easier to debug your code.

Comment: Its hiding because of `overflow` property of `table-responsive` class

Comment: I know...do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- An absolutely positioned element is actually positioned regarding a
  relative parent, or the nearest found relative parent, which means it
  bubbles up the DOM until it finds a relative context to apply the
  positioning.
- If no relative parent is found it will then reach the highest
  possible `« container »`, which is the browser window, aka the `viewport` (or the document maybe, or the window … ? hey you know what,
  I'm not a W3C expert ok!).

Now You just need to set position static to relative element

In your case:

```
.dataTables_wrapper {
    position: static;
    clear: both;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w11hwLLy/1/)

[Source](http://front-back.com/how-to-make-absolute-positioned-elements-overlap-their-overflow-hidden-parent)